# Plain Old DNS on Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

I need to setup a DNS server which will host DNS for all my public domains, I have read numerous articles all explaining how to setup for a coporate network which seems to be of no help to me. I dont want to use AD Domain Services either just the DNS server role.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Not programming...

Comment: What specific areas do you need help with? Are you comfortable with how DNS works in general? Install DNS (can't remember if its a role or a feature offhand), create your forward and reverse zones and populate it. Each step is simple enough.

Answer (score 3):

Windows dns supports non-integrated zones just fine. They're called 'primary zone's if I remember right, and they work as well as BIND does. It just needs the dns role and that should be all you need.

Answer (score 2):

You were not clear about which OS, so the assumption is Windows 2008...
check out this link...
http://www.zdnetasia.com/install-a-dns-server-in-windows-server-2008-62040433.htm

like sysadmin1138 said. Just install the service and configure your zones as normal. If this is for public domains, remember to ask your ISP to redirect reverse lookups to your server. This is especially important for mail servers these days.